# html file loads with file:/// but not with http://

Tags: javascript, html, apache, nginx

I have an html file containing code for an ad. The ad loads fine when opened using `file:///full/path/file.html` but when I host the same file on live environment and access using `http://example.com/file.html` the ad doesnt load. I have inspected the network traffic that the file generates and noticed that some network calls fire with `file:///` but not with `http://` (e.g. rolling.js).
I have tried hosting the file on WAMP, NGINX on both windows and ubuntu and tried opening it but no luck. I have also tried same on both localhost and remote server.

My question is what does file:/// do different than http:// that file:/// is able to render the code? I know a different source where the same file is being hosted and works with http://. I have tried making the webservers return same response headers as the only place i know where it works with http:// but it didnt work for me. It might be something very small but I have not been able to figure it out. Here is the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://nym1-ib.adnxs.com/ab?e=wqT_3QKQGfA8kAwAAAMA1gAFAQiRrci8BRCesp7bjceRoj4Y_ff72dK69vF-IAEqLQlq-1dWmpS-PxEhgfVu4pq6PxkAAAECDPA_ISENEgApESSoMIjfhwM40ApAmA1IrAFQsZ2GFliEhjhgAGiB1Ap4vvsBgAEBigEDVVNEkgUG8LSYAaABoAHYBKgBAbABALgBAsABBcgBAtABCdgBAOABAPABANgCyAPgAqOMBuoCTGh0dHA6Ly93d3cuc2V0eHNwb3J0cy5jb20vaXAvaW5kZXgucGhwPy9mb3J1bS8xMTktaGlnaC1zY2hvb2wtYmFzZWJhbGwtMjAxNi_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-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..&s=56841a1b1b786c2356fb3fe8bd3d16b239d1173c&referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.setxsports.com%2Fip%2Findex.php%3F%2Fforum%2F119-high-school-baseball-2016%2F&pp=0.103926"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the url of ad? the one in script tag?

Comment: The url in script tag brings some iframes, which then fire some more calls and the ad renders after about 30 or so calls in network traffic with file:///.. But with http:// it mostly stops at 5 or 6 network calls. The same file is hosted here http://html5.iabtechlab.com/work/runzip/adTagFile_1470041795928/index.html and it works, but when i host it, it doesnt. :/

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if page url has mixed HTTP and HTTPS content.
2. Try different Browsers since flash content may be blocked by certain ones
3. Check if there is a [CORS](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) issue blocking content outside your server
4. Disable Firewall

Comment: The answer "disable firewall" should never be recommended. If the firewall was the problem, either speak to or learn from someone who can adjust the firewall rules.

Comment: I thought that it was self explanatory that this is not a permanent action and just for spotting the issues. Then the specific port can be opened. Running a server on localhost for development can be tricky. I remember having issues with Apache 8080 and AVG antivirus.

Comment: I have already tried different browsers. Just tried http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html on nginx, and also tried disable firewall.. but no luck.. The page does have mixed http and https content, what will be the solution in that case?